# Add OnLoad() in Page_Load()?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onload, pageload

I have a few Database things to read in the Page_Load of my Asp.net page.

```
if (xxx == 1)
  //Add OnLoad("clock()")
```

How to do this?
How to add a OnLoad-Method for a JavaScript clock in the page load method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st Make your body tag a servercontrol

```
<body runat="server" id="BodyTag">
```

2nd reference it like

```
if (xxx == 1)  
  BodyTag.Attributes.Add("onload", "clock()");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` method to add client code to the page:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
  this.GetType(),
  "onload",
  "window.onload = function(){ clock(); }",
  true
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Register a startup script in the `Page_Load`. ClientScriptManager (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) or ScriptManager (h[ttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx](http://ttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx))... whichever is appropriate.

```
string clockStuff =
    @"function callClockFunction(){ 
    Sys.Application.remove_load(callClockFunction); 
    clock(); }
    Sys.Application.add_load(callClockFunction);";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "callClockFunction", clockStuff, true);
```